# Hibernate daemon update

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a quite an update-intensive application and was wondering if it is a good idea to have a daemon thread that has a hibernate session and that takes update instructions and groups those updates into a batch (which I guess is more efficient).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your use-cases trigger many updates, but those updates are not necessary to be executed right when they are triggered (like the data they would add is not mandatory on the spot) you can and in fact it is advised to store them and execute them at a later time (like at night, or when the application is less heavily hit). You don't necessarely need a daemon (or any kind of) thread for that, just store your update requests somewhere, and then have a CRON Job or something be triggered at certain intervals and execute them. You can use [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) for this, it will deal with all the underlying threads/scheduling.

Also regarding batching multiple queries vs. executing them idividually, normally Hibernate takes care of that (like if you issue multiple update requests in the same transaction Hibernate will batch them togehter and execute them at the latest possible time - usually when the transactio ends), so this shouldn't be a concern for you. What MIGHT become a concern, depening on your number of update requests , would be Hibernate itself. At some point you might want to consider using JDBC and batch execute those updates manually to gain performance.